# Laravel recursive relationships don't work

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have following table structure:

```
Categories
id | title    | parent_id | order | active
1    example    null        1       1
2    example    1           null    1
3    example    2           null    1
```

I need to retrieve all children categories in one collection, so i have two functions for this:

```
public function children()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Category', 'parent_id')
        ->where('active', 1);
}
public function childrenRecursive()
{
    return $this->children()->with('childrenRecursive');
}
```

I run `Category::find(1)->childrenRecursive` and must get all children categories but I get only 1 level nested categories. What is the problem?

P.S. Laravel 6.18.22

Comment: Please add the output of `dd(Category::with('childrenRecursive')->find(1)->toArray())` to your question (with or without `toArray()`; I find the output easier to read with `toArray()`, but you can omit it if you want)

Comment: It returns same result, 1 level nested categories, I checked it

Comment: Is there a reason you didn't add it to your question? I want to help, but if you're not willing to add that, I can't.

Comment: I can add this but in my project other real categories which not alike on example in question. It returns additional `childrenRecursive` field that contains also 1 level nested categories

Comment: The reason I was asking you to add that output is so that I could show you that the relationships are in fact loaded recursively, but also that you have to actually loop over everything (again, recursively) to get more than a single level deep. Each record can have a `children` properly, and calling `$category->children` **does not get all levels deep**. Please cooperate with the people asking for clarification, otherwise you hinder our ability to help you. Also, `childrenRecursive` is a recursive relationship loader; you don't call that on an instance, use `->children` instead.

Comment: Yes, I saw that other categories loaded as `childrenRecursive` field for their parent, but this i can get anytime called `$category->children->children`. I need to get all children categories in one collection to work with it and I want to have this recursive method in my model.

Comment: Then you're going to have to recursively flatten them into a single Collection: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/collections#method-flatten. Also, `$category->children->children` wouldn't work; you'd have to do iteration, like `foreach($category->children as $child){ // do something with $child->children }`, etc.

Comment: Ok. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

this code should be helpful:

```
    Category::where('id', 1)->with('childrenRecursive')->get();
```

or

```
    Category::where(['active'=> 1, 'parent_id' => null])->with('childrenRecursive')->get();
```

Comment: You should add a reason _why_ this is a good answer. This will help answer the question, and allow someone else with a similar issue to figure out why their code does not work.